# Object as parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to hand over an Object, like a div , as a parameter for a function in JavaScript? Something like :

```
function isInsideViewPort(ele){
    bounding = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
    if(bounding.top < window.innerHeight && bounding.left < window.innerWidth){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

where ele is for example a div ? If yes is it also possible to call this function with onload in html and hand over a "this" like in java?

Comment: Did you try it? Give it a shot first before asking.

Comment: 1. Open console 2. write function that takes an object 3. find or generate some HTMLElement 4. CALL :D 5. does it work?

Comment: Yes, passing objects is possible. You could simply try it in your browser console. I’m not sure what you mean by “hand over a ‘this’”.

Comment: Yeah i tried it with alert(isInsideViewPort(document.getElementById("...")); and nothing happened. Then i deleted the call and Just wrote alert("hi"); to check if It works and it worked , so Something is wrong on the upper call and i already searched for answers on the Internet .

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that. Even though in jQuery it is more simple:

```
$ele = $('.mydiv'); // Where "mydiv" is the class of the div of interes (alternatively use an id or whatever)
```

Alternative in javascript:

```
jele = document.getElementByClassName("mydiv");
```

Then call your function and do whatever you like with it.

```
isInsideViewPort($ele);
```

Or:

```
isInsideViewPort(jele)
```